# Magento 2 How to get all existing values for one attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I need to get all existing values for a custom product attribute.

> Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'manufacturer_name',
    [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Manufacturer Name',
        'input' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'used_for_sort_by' => false,
        'group' => 'Roche',
        'sort_order' => 10
    ]
);
```

Assuming that the following data is present in the database

```
| product_id | manufacturer_name |
|------------+-------------------|
| 1          | Manufacturer 1    |
| 2          | Manufacturer 1    |
| 3          | NULL              |
| 4          | Manufacturer 2    |
```

I want to retrieve the following list

```
  Manufacturer 1
  Manufacturer 2
```

I've try the following code but it doesn't work, it always return a empty array.

> Block/Manufacturers.php

```
/**
 * Get all manufacturers list
 * @return array
 */
public function getManufacturerListing()
{
    $attributes = $this->eavAttributeRepository->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,'manufacturer_name');
    $options = $attributes->getSource()->getAllOptions(true,true);
    return $options;
}
```

Do I need to create a  SQL request with a join or something like that ? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it. The following code return exactly what I want :

> Block/Manufacturers.php

```
/**
 * Get all manufacturers list
 * @return array
 */
public function getManufacturerListing()
{
    $productCollection = $this->manager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $productCollection->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer_name')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer_name', array('notnull' => true))// get only not null values
        ->getSelect()->group('manufacturer_name');// only get once each same value
    return $collection;
}
```

I just select the needed attribute and filter not null values (as a kind of `array_filter`)

> view/templates/manufacturers.phtml

```
<select name="manufacturer">
    <?php foreach ($block->getManufacturerListing() as $product): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $product->getManufacturerName() ?>"> <?php echo __($product->getManufacturerName()); ?> </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I retrieve a `ProductInterceptor` objects collection in my template so I just call the "magic" method `getManufacturerName()` based on my custom product attribute name to retrieve the value of attribute.

It works perfectly!

Comment: I did exactly the same thing but got the error: Invalid attribute name: manufacturer_name. I've used addAttributeToSelect('*') also but my collection doesn't load all the attributes of products.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
protected $_eavAttribute;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttribute
) {
    $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
}

public function getManufacturerListing()
{ 
    $manufacturerAttr = $this->_eavAttribute->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer_name');
    $allOptions = $manufacturerAttr->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    return $allOptions;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the Below Code and try :

**1. Inside your block file,**

```
  protected $eavAttributeRepository;

  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
      \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttributeRepository
  ){
      parent::__construct($context);
      $this->eavAttributeRepository = $eavAttributeRepository;
   }

  public function getManufacturerListing(){
      $attributes = $this->eavAttributeRepository->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,'manufacturer_name');
      $options = $attributes->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
      return $options;
  }
```

**2. Inside your phtml file,**

```
 $optionList = $block->getManufacturerListing();
 foreach ($optionList as $value) {
     //print_r($value);
     echo $value['label'];
 }
```